# Why does Lua default to global variables?

Tags: lua

My favourite language these days is Lua. I have only one issue with it, why on earth is its default behaviour that variables in functions are global? In the similar language Icon there is a keyword "global" that is used when one really wants to use a global instead of the natural behaviour to default to local (I was bitten by this again five minutes ago). I would feel better about this if somebody could tell me the rational behind it (like the scoping difficulties that I know cause the absence of a "continue" keyword in Lua).

Comment: Thanks lhf for the complete answer. And Lua uFAQ is new to me. Really good indeed! And through your link I discovered http://lua-users.org/wiki/DetectingUndefinedVariables. The tricks there solves the practical issue for me.

Answer (score 19):

See [Why aren't variables locally scoped by default?](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.18.1) in the [Lua uFAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/).

> It certainly feels easy to only explicitly declare globals when they are in a local context. The short answer is that Lua is not Python, but there are actually good reasons why lexically-scoped local variables have to be explicitly declared. See the [wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LocalByDefault).

Comment: Can you include relevant quote from the wiki? You know that answers on [so] should not be link-only.

Comment: ["The problem is that without local declarations, you cannot say where the variable is local to." (RiciLake)](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-10/msg00063.html)[via the referenced Lua User's Wiki]—salient and succinct.